# How to split 3d matrix into sub-2d matrices?

Tags: matlab

I have a 3d matrix (40 x 32 x 408). I want to split it to the separate matrix like this:

1 x 1 x 1 (Get first value of firs dimension and first value of second dimension, first of third dim)

1 x 1 x 2 (Get first value of firs dimension and first value of second dimension, second of third dim)

1 x 1 x 3 (Get first value of firs dimension and first value of second dimension, third of third dim)

...

1 x 1 * 408

Be a separate 3d matrix.

Then:

1 x 2 x 1 (Get first value of firs dimension and second value of second dimension)

1 x 2 x 2

1 x 2 x 3

...

1 x 2 x 408

Be another separate matrix; and continue this for all 32 values. Also similar for 40 dimensions:

2 x 1 x 1 (Get second value of firs dimension and first value of second dimension)

2 x 1 x 2

2 x 1 x 3

...

2 x 1 x 408

And so on. So in that way (at the end), I must have 40 x 32 = 1280 separate 3d matrix which the third dimension for all of them starts in 1 and ends in 408.

[Here is the google drive link for downloading my 3d Matrix](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QWJG3H-mdnEyzLikCG_ko4Gpb1G6Czlj)

more description:

This 3d Matrix (Latitude x Longitude x Time) belongs to gridded precipitation for a climate model named GPCC. As you can see its includes data for 408 months across 1280 points (40 x 32) covering my case study. I want to consider every point like a point-based data and produce 408-month data for them. So every 1280 point has it's owned data (let be precipitation) for 408 months. And then I can use them in the [Standardized Drought Analysis Toolbox (SDAT)](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/51080-nonparametric-standardized-precipitation-index-spi) which is a third party function that presents in Matlab file exchange by Professor [Amir Aghakouchak](http://amir.eng.uci.edu/) for calculating SPI (Standardized Precipitation Index).

Comment: Why not just access it with `mat(1,1,:)` for the first matrix (possibly adding a `squeeze`)? What shape do you want the resulting matrices?

Comment: Dear @beaker Thank you this is a very good mention. I should use mat(1,1,:) and then squeeze. many thanks. 
I was wondering how to write a loop-for in this purpose because I'm not coder and I'm new in Matlab and not familiar with many functions.

Comment: @beaker I want the result to be a cell that contains all output as separate tables in first rows. I try to write a for-loop for doing this but still, I can't write the correct code. anyway, I'm happy because you mentioned mat(1,1,:) and squeeze. if you please help in writing for-loop I would be so grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are describing the behaviour of [`num2cell`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html) when the argument `dim` is `3`.

```
C = num2cell(A,3)
```

will assign a cell array with one of your 40×32 matrices in each cell to `C`, where `A` is the name of your original 3D matrix.